# how to use dbpedia to retrieve language specific information?

Tags: wikipedia, dbpedia

I am trying to learn dbpedia, from the tutorial I read, for url such as:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Christian_Fabricius

dbpedia creates an url such as:
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Johan_Christian_Fabricius, which I can use to lots of useful information.

But for the chinese verion of wikipedia, the url is:
http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BA%A6%E7%BF%B0%C2%B7%E5%85%8B%E9%87%8C%E6%96%AF%E8%92%82%E5%AE%89%C2%B7%E6%B3%95%E5%B8%83%E9%87%8C%E4%B8%98%E6%96%AF

how can I use dbpedia to retrieve information from Chinese site?

Comment: DBpedia is a triple store. You need to query it. Your question is very vague, because what you are referring to in a wiki page. The dbpedia is this: http://dbpedia.org/page/Johan_Christian_Fabricius.

Comment: no, my question is very specific. I provided a chinese verion of wikipedia. and I would like to see how to use depeida to retrieve from this page? As http://dbpedia.org/resource/ChineseNameForJohanChristianFabricius doesn't work. The ChineseNameForJohanChristianFabricius is what specified in the zh.wikipedia.org url.

Comment: I don't think there is a Chinese version of dbpedia.